# Obtain the Sum of an IEnumerable collection in only one LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

Let's suppose I have an inifite generator `A()`. What I want is to obtain the sum of all the numbers returned by `A` such that the sum does not exceed a value `N` **in only one LINQ expression**.

I'm wondering if there is an extension method that will help me with that?

The classic way would be:

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (int x in A()) {
    sum += x;
    if (sum > N) {
        break;
    }
}

return sum;
```

but I've been thinking about how to do it in only one expression without success...

Comment: Do you mean a single method call or a single statement?

Answer (score 3):

If `A` is an infinite generator then there's no way of doing this in a single statement using only the built-in LINQ methods.

To do it cleanly, in a single statement, with no side-effects, you'd probably need to use some sort of [`Scan`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/scanl1_f.html) method to compute the [prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) of the input sequence. Then you just need the first element greater than `N`. Easy!

```
int sum = A().Scan((s, x) => s + x).First(s => s > N);

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Scan<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, T> func)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (func == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("func");

        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (e.MoveNext())
            {
                T accumulator = e.Current;
                yield return accumulator;

                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    accumulator = func(accumulator, e.Current);
                    yield return accumulator;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `PrefixAggregate` might be a better name than `Scan`?

Comment: @Timwi: `Scan` is the name that seems to be used in functional programming for this family of functions: See [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340364.aspx) and [Haskell](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/scanl1_f.html), for example. I believe there's a scan implementation included in the Reactive Extensions too (but I don't have RX installed here so I can't check for sure.)

Comment: @LukeH, doesn't this still use two LINQ-expressions in the top line? (both Scan(...) and First(...))

Comment: @JBSnorro: It's a single *statement*, and the right-hand side of the `=` is a single expression.

Comment: @LukeH: True, but the problem stated to use only a single LINQ expression... not statement, nor regular expression(e.g. a chain of LINQ expressions)

Comment: @JBSnorro: How are you going to assign the result of the expression to anything without it being part of a statement? If you want a single expression then `A().Scan((s, x) => s + x).First(s => s > N)` is it (a compound expression is still a single expression); if you want to assign that result to something then you're going to need to use a statement, as your own answer does too.

Answer (score 3):

Using standard idiomatic LINQ, this would be impossible.  The semantics you would need is a combination of `Aggregate()` and `TakeWhile()`.  Otherwise, you'd need to have side-effects which is a no-no in LINQ.

Here's an example of one way to do it with side-effects:

```
var temp = 0;
var sum = A().TakeWhile(i =>
{
    var res = !(temp > N);
    temp += i;
    return res;
}).Sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is a way to do this with a single LINQ-expression. The simplest I could come up with and still have some generality and elegance is:

```
public static int SumWhile(this IEnumerable<int> collection, Func<int, bool> condition)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (int i in collection)
    {
        sum += i;
        if (!condition(sum))
            break;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

which can be called like:

```
int sum = A().SumWhile(i => i <= N);
```

Yeah, just a single LINQ-expression! Have fun with it

Comment: There is a slight inconsistency in the question: Oscar asks for the sum not to exceed N, while in his code it does(which I've also implemented). That makes the name of my method a little irksome, since it doesn't _sum while some condition_, but _sums while some condition and the next_.... I feel like I should mention this

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most near your initial idea :

```
int sum = 0;
int limit = 500;
A().TakeWhile(i => (sum += i) < limit).Count();
//Now the variable named sum contains the smaller sum of elements being >= limit
```

The Count() isn't used for its returning value but to force the actual enumerating.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I have the requirements correct.

A() is an infinite generator. By definition, then, it generates values (in this case integers) forever.

You want to look for *all* of the values that are less than N, and add them together.

Linq isn't the issue. You won't be done adding until A() is finished generating... and that never happens.

BTW, the code you posted doesn't all up all of the values less than N... it adds up all the values until it finds one less than N, and then it quits looking. Is that what you meant?

Comment: He wants to keep adding until the **sum** is more than N.

Comment: I fixed the code. I wrote it on the fly. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the horrific code below satisfies your requirements. :-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication12 {
  public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      const int N=100;

      int sum;
      try {
        sum=A().Aggregate((self, next) => {
          if(self+next<=N)
            return self+next;
          else
            throw new ResultException(self);
        });
      } catch(ResultException re) {
        sum=re.Value;
      }
      Debug.Print("Sum="+sum);
    }

    private class ResultException : Exception {
      public readonly int Value;

      public ResultException(int value) {
        Value=value;
      }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> A() {
      var i=0;
      while(true) {
        yield return i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

int sum = A().Where(x => x < N).Sum();

Comment: The sum has to be less than N. I missed that on my first runthrough also.

Comment: @Ritch, why do you think that? The code given by Oscar, who asked the question, also yields a value greater than N.

Comment: @JBSnorro The OP edited it a bit. The sum must be greater than N, not each individual x < N, or x > N.